# Finding centralizer of a matrix in general linear group.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I saw the following question from Gallian's book on abstract algebra.

I am required to find the centralizer of the matrix
$$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
in the general real linear group of $2\times2$ matrices.

I took a general matrix 
$$B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and found their product BA and AB which are
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a+b & a \\
        c+d & c \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a+c & b+d \\
        a & b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
respectively. But I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: You are almost done. Just equate $AB=BA$ and find values of $a$ $b$ $c$ and $d$ satisfying this and $ad\neq bc$ as you need non-zero determinant. You will get them all in terms of one variable.

Comment: Awesome. I got it. Thanks Rise. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can start by claiming the two products are equal and then this will determine your coefficients. For example you can immediately see that $b$ must be equal to $c$, and you should be able to get the other relations from here.

Comment: Yes. I got the matrix $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a+b & a \\
        a &  b \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$ but I'm not getting the constraint(s) in terms of a and b alone.

Comment: I don't see the problem. The answer is all matrices of this form. You are done!